# Relationship between /etc/hosts and iptables?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, iptables, centos6

I'm running a [DigitalOcean](https://digitalocean.com) Centos 6 VPS. Here's the script I used to set up `iptables` on Centos 6.4 64-bit:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
service iptables stop
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8181
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
service iptables restart
```

I opens ports 22, 80 and 443 only, redirecting 80 and 443 internally to 8080 and 8181 respectively.

Due to a bug/quirk in GlassFish, I had to add the machine's hostname to `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

Without the NAT rules in the `iptables` configuration, I am able to reach the GlassFish server via my browser at home when attempting to connect either via port 8080 or 8181. With the NAT rules added, I cannot reach the server at all, neither via 80 and 443 nor via 8080 and 8181.

Do I need to make a change to any of the `iptables` rules to factor in that extra line in `/etc/hosts`?

**Update:**

If I remove the last rule, `iptables -P INPUT DROP`, I can now access the server via a browser using ports 80/443 and 8080/8181. This indicate the forwarding is working.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is NO, No you don't.

The longer answer is that /etc/hosts is there to assist the networking stack resolver.  The resolver is the part of the IP stack (TCP/IP v4 and v6) that is responsible for converting friendly names, such as mybigserver, to an IP address, such as 172.16.0.1.

In your post you are showing us a script and the script is running IPTable commands.

The script is using the PREROUTING chain to do NAT but you state in your question that you are unable to reach "GlassFish" server via the browser.....

1. What browser?  Browser on the same Linux host or a browser on another computer connected to the same switch as ETH0?

If the answer to #1 is another host connected to the same switch as your Linux ETH0, then the problem is you need to change your NAT rules to use the POSTROUTING chain.  The reason being you want to NAT the outbound connection.  What you have setup is PAT (Port Address Translation).

If this is your setup
[Your Browser]------[network switch]-----[ETH0 Linux ETH1]-----{Public Internet]

Then replace these lines

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8181
```

with:

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth1
```

If this resolves your issue, then you can fine tune that POSTROUTING rule to use a range of ports and/or a specific ETH1 IP if it's multi-homed.

Comment: GlassFish is running in a data center (digitalocean.com). My browser is running on my home Internet connection. I will clarify that in the question.

Comment: Question edited. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: oh-I-C: You want to connect TO this server.  This VPS box is listening on an IP address bound to ETH0 and port 80 & 443 which you are PATing the connection.  Why do you need PAT if, presumably, the ETH0 is public facing?  If you're looking to limit port exposure, you should just stick with iptables -t filter rules and just get rid of the PREROUTING stuff.  IPTABLES -A INPUT is changing the filter table.

Comment: I don't want to run GlassFish as root if I can avoid it. Regular users can't listen on ports < 1024.

Comment: @Steve:  Not familiar with GlassFish; but can't you change the port GlassFish listens on from 80 & 443 to 8080 and 8181 somewhere?

Comment: Yes I can do that. I will also have to grant its user account permission to listen on privileged ports. That's something I'd rather avoid if possible.

Comment: @Steve: Why will you have to grant its user account to listen on a privileged port if you "can do that" means you can change the GlassFish server to listen on an unpriv port?  Many Linux processes often are launched by root but then switch to a jailed or regular/unpriv user account.  But if you claim you can change the port, then you should be all set.  No need to run as root...

Comment: How can I have GlassFish (or any other service) launched as root then switch to a jailed user account while allowing it to listen on a privileged port? I would have thought that, by definition, putting a process in jail means you put it in jail.

Comment: I thought you had stated that you can change GlassFish configuration to listen on a non-priv port.  What does "Yes I can do that." refer too?

Comment: You do not need a priv account if you can change your GlassFish configuration to start up and use 8080 and 8181...

Comment: It already uses 8080 and 8181. The iptables rules I have set up are supposed to redirect incoming requests on ports 80/443 to 8080/8181, yet GlassFish is not receiving these requests on ports 8080/8181. I do however need privileges to bind GlassFish directly to ports 80/443 which is what you suggested a few comments up.

Comment: I suggested changing to 80/443 before I knew of your constraint to not run as priv account.  What I say above is get rid of the iptables -t nat rules if this is the case and connect directly to the GlassFish server without going through a PAT.  Remove the two iptables -t nat lines and it should work.  I say above that if you need to block off more ports from public Internet, use filter chain.

Comment: OK. I don't want to run as root so I will have to grant the user the privileges to listen on ports 80 and 443. You said above that I don't need to do that, but I can't see how I can run as a non-root user and listen on those ports without that user being granted a privilege to do so.

Comment: @Steve: You're not making sense.  Just remove the two iptables lines and let GlassFish listen on the unpriv ports 8080 and 8181; you will need to append 8080 and 8181 accordingly to your URIs.  Maybe I assumed you understood that point.  If you insist on using 80 and 443 or no URI modifications you might be able to do an HTTP redirect if GlassFish supports that but then you're back to SOMETHING needing to camp out on 80 and 443 to either do the redirect or GlassFish..

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

You don't ACCEPT packets to either 8080 or 8181 in your rules!

### Longer answer

> Without the NAT rules in the iptables configuration, I am able to reach the GlassFish server via my browser at home when attempting to connect either via port 8080 or 8181. With the NAT rules added, I cannot reach the server at all, neither via 80 and 443 nor via 8080 and 8181.

This is because your rules work, and thereby forward 80 and 443 to 8080 and 8181! But you forgot to also **ACCEPT** connections to those! Which is why all of them are rejected!

> If I remove the last rule, iptables -P INPUT DROP, I can now access the server via a browser using ports 80/443 and 8080/8181. This indicate the forwarding is working.

Should make sense now:

- Request to Port 8080 >> DROP (default)
- Request to Port 8181 >> DROP (default)
- Request to Port 80  >> Port 8080 >> DROP (default)
- Request to Port 443  >> Port 8181 >> DROP (default)

Without the last line you have the default of ACCEPT instead of DROP so of course it works then.

### Solution

Add following two rules ...

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8181 -j ACCEPT
```

... and it should work with the default INPUT DROP line (Port 80 >> Port 8080 >> ACCEPT (rule)).